# Itext GifImage first inputstream not closed

Tags: java, itext

I have a problem with the com.itextpdf.text.pdf.codec.GifImage.
In the constructor GifImage(URL url) the inputstream is used twice but only once closed.
If the stream isn't closed the file (temporary image) can not be deleted.

```
public GifImage(URL url) throws IOException {
    fromUrl = url;
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = url.openStream();   // first use

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            baos.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        is = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());   // second use
        baos.flush();
        baos.close();

        process(is);
    }
    finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Do you want us to add an `is.close()` before `is` is reused?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/6423/) should solve your problem:

[image]

Comment: Why re-assign is in the first place? Wouldn't the code be clearer by using a different variable for the `ByteArrayInputStream` (which has a `close()` method that has no effect anyway). Just nitpicking. ;-)